# Should I install Doom 3 BFG Edition on my hard drive on my XBOX?

Tags: xbox-360, doom-3-bfg-edition

One can install this game to his harddrive. Are there any benefits in doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is actually a bad idea.

Developers from id Software outlined that it will have no advantage in doing so.
Additionally, it will actually prevent you from playing Doom I+II which come with that game.

[Source](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/10/18/psa-dont-install-doom-3-on-xbox-360-if-you-want-to-play-doom-1/)

Comment: Wow. Thats.... stupid.